# Python - Using the Multiply Operator to Create Copies of Objects in Lists

Tags: python, list

In Python, if I multiply of list of objects by an integer, I get a list of references to that object, e.g.:

```
>>> a = [[]] * 3
>>> a
[[], [], []]
>>> a[0].append(1)
>>> a
[[1], [1], [1]]
```

If my desired behavior is to create a list of copies of the original object (e.g. copies created by the "copy.copy()" method or something sort of standard, is there an *elegant* way to do this *with the same multiplication operator*?  Or should I just stick with a list comprehension or something?  E.g.

```
[[] for x in range(0,3)]
```

Any version of Python is fine.

Comment: Best duplicate target: [Python list of lists, Changes Reflected Across Sublists Unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/240178)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The multiplication operator on a sequence means repetition of the item(s) -- NOT creation of copies (shallow or deep ones) of the items. Nothing stops you from going crazy, a la:

```
import copy

class Crazy(object):
  def __init__(self, body, weird=copy.copy):
    self.gomez = body
    self.cousinitt = weird
  def __mul__(self, n):
    return [self.cousinitt(x) for x in (self.gomez * n)]

a = Crazy([[]]) * 3
```

...except your sanity and common sense, if any. Checking on those, how DID you dream operator `*` could be made to mean something utterly different than it's intended to mean, except by defining another class overloading `__mul__` in weird ways...?-)

Comment: While I understand your emphasis on this being weird, wouldn't it be easier (and more generally useful) to inherit from the `list` class so that we have all the grunt list-handling work done for us, and simply overload the `__mul__` operator to do copying?

Comment: Your point is lost to me with the weird example.

Comment: No need to be rude

Answer (score 19):

This is a good usage of list comprehension - its also the most readable way to do it IMO.

So the `[[] for x in range(0,3)]` you suggest isn't the multiplication operator, but gets the result you want.

Answer (score 2):

The list comprehension is the best way to do this. If you define a new class and overload the * operator, it will seriously confuse the next person to read the code.