# Python - Dynamic Nested List

Tags: python, list, nested

So I'm trying to generate a nested list in Python based on a width and a height. This is what I have so far:

```
    width = 4
    height = 5
    row = [None]*width
    map = [row]*height
```

Now, this obviously isn't quite right. When printed it looks fine:

```
[[None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None]]
```

But attempting to assign a value to a position like so:

```
map[2][3] = 'foo'
```

I get:

```
[[None, None, None, 'foo'],
 [None, None, None, 'foo'],
 [None, None, None, 'foo'],
 [None, None, None, 'foo'],
 [None, None, None, 'foo']]
```

Clearly this happens because each sublist is really just referencing the same object, row, so changing one, changes them all. So this is closest I've got!

How can I dynamically generate a nested list? Thanks!

Comment: While not an exact duplicate, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605024/python-using-the-multiply-operator-to-create-copies-of-objects-in-lists

Comment: `map()` is a built-in function, it's not a good idea to override it. Find another name, if needed you can just append `_`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you do `[row]*height` you end up with the same list object in each row. The `row` array reference is repeated in each row which means each row is actually pointing to the same list object. Hence modifying one row actually modifies all rows.

Take a look at what happens when you print the [`id()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id) for each row. They're all the same!

```
>>> grid = [[None] * width] * height
>>> [id(row) for row in grid]
[148014860, 148014860, 148014860, 148014860, 148014860]
```

You can get python to generate separate-but-identical lists for each row by using a list comprehension. When you use `[rowexpr for i in xrange(height)]` then `rowexpr` will be evaluated once per row. The trick then is to use an expression that will result in a unique list each time it is evaluated.

This'll make more sense if you see it in action:

```
>>> grid = [[None] * width for i in xrange(height)]
>>> grid[2][3] = 'foo'
>>> grid
[[None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, 'foo'],
 [None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None]]
```

Each time `[None] * width` is evaluated it generates a new list.

```
>>> [id(row) for row in grid]
[148016172, 148015212, 148016236, 148016108, 148016332]
```

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this:

```
w = 5
h = 5

map = []

for i in range(h):
 row = []
 for j in range(w):
  row.append(None)
 map.append(row)

print map

map[2][3] = 'foo'

print map
```

Comment: I agree, list comprehension is cleaner, more readable, more 'Pythonic'. My way is just a way to solve the problem and also readable for people (like me) who are still evolving from C to python.

Comment: doing it with nested for loops doesn't help you or anyone else make the transition from C to python: It just gets in the way.