# appending to a nested list in python

Tags: python, list, nested, append

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)
>   [Python - Using the Multiply Operator to Create Copies of Objects in Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605024/python-using-the-multiply-operator-to-create-copies-of-objects-in-lists)

Python behaves unexpected when i append to a list, which is in another list. Here's an example:

```
>>> _list = [[]] * 7
>>> _list
[[], [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>> _list[0].append("value")
```

What i expect:

```
>>> _list
[['value'], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

What i get:

```
>>> _list
[['value'], ['value'], ['value'], ['value'], ['value'], ['value'], ['value']]
```

Why is this? how can i go around it?

Comment: also: [Python - Dynamic Nested List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587215/python-dynamic-nested-list?rq=1)

Comment: @Jacob I don't see a default argument here... it is a similiar effect, but not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your list does not contain seven independent lists, but rather the *same* list seven times.

To create a list of list, better use a list comprehension:

```
_list = [[] for _ in xrange(7)]
```

which will result in a list containing seven different lists.

Comment: That actually makes sense, thanks