# append to a nested list in python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I am trying to make a playfair cipher but I am having trouble getting my variables into the right spot.

I have a function that encodes 2 plaintext letters at a time and return the encoded equivalent but it only accepts 2 args of the single letter(in string). I need help getting seperating my list then encoding the pair.

This is what I have

```
def function(plaintext):
    temp_hold = ''
    encode_out = ''

    sendout = ''

    #breaks into pairs of 2 (list within a list)
    temp_hold = [plaintext[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(plaintext), 2)]

    for i in range(len(temp_hold)):
        for j in range(len(temp_hold)):
            encode_out = encode_pair(temp_hold[i][j], temp_hold[i][j])
    print encode_out
    # encode pair takes (a,b) and returns its encoded value

print function("abcd") # should print HSCI
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [appending to a nested list in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763157/appending-to-a-nested-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Should you really have a nested loop?  Shouldn't it be ...

```
for letter1, letter2 in temp_hold:
    encode_out = encode_pair(letter1, letter2)
    print encode_out
```

Comment: Thanks that worked but how would this work if I had a sentence rather than abcd?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by a sentence. Do spaces and punctuation need to be ignored?

Comment: yea with no spaces and punctuation

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to look into it.  You can probably find helpful information by doing a google search.