# Generating sublists using multiplication ( * ) unexpected behavior

Tags: python, list, nested-lists, mutable

I'm sure this has been answered somewhere but I wasn't sure how to describe it.

Let's say I want to create a list containing 3 empty lists, like so:

```
lst = [[], [], []]
```

I thought I was being all clever by doing this:

```
lst = [[]] * 3
```

But I discovered, after debugging some weird behavior, that this caused an append update to one sublist, say `lst[0].append(3)`, to update the entire list, making it `[[3], [3], [3]]` rather than `[[3], [], []]`.

However, if I initialize the list with

```
lst = [[] for i in range(3)]
```

then doing `lst[1].append(5)`gives the expected `[[], [5], []]`

My question is **why does this happen**? It is interesting to note that if I do

```
lst = [[]]*3
lst[0] = [5]
lst[0].append(3)
```

then the 'linkage' of cell 0 is broken and I get `[[5,3],[],[]]`, but `lst[1].append(0)` still causes `[[5,3],[0],[0]`.

My best guess is that using multiplication in the form `[[]]*x` causes Python to store a reference to a single cell...?

Comment: @RoadieRich But the answers here have better explanation and links to official documentation.

Comment: @AseemBansal: Then those answers should be added to the *other* question instead perhaps?

Comment: It's definitively a duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/unexpected-feature-in-a-python-list-of-lists and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605024/python-using-the-multiply-operator-to-create-copies-of-objects-in-lists and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688223/python-list-multiplication-3-makes-3-lists-which-mirror-each-other-when?lq=1 and others I can't find right now.

Comment: I flagged the 3 questions to be marked as duplicates.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> My best guess is that using multiplication in the form `[[]] * x` causes Python to store a reference to a single cell...?

Yes. And you can test this yourself

```
>>> lst = [[]] * 3
>>> print [id(x) for x in lst]
[11124864, 11124864, 11124864]
```

This shows that all three references refer to the same object. And note that it *really* makes perfect sense that this happens<sup>1</sup>. It just copies the *values*, and in this case, the values *are* references. And that's why you see the same reference repeated three times.

> It is interesting to note that if I do

```
lst = [[]]*3
lst[0] = [5]
lst[0].append(3)
```

> then the 'linkage' of cell 0 is broken and I get `[[5,3],[],[]]`, but `lst[1].append(0)` still causes `[[5,3],[0],[0]`.

You changed the reference that occupies `lst[0]`; that is, you assigned a new *value* to `lst[0]`. But you didn't change the *value* of the other elements, they still refer to the same object that they referred to. And `lst[1]` and `lst[2]` still refer to exactly the same instance, so of course appending an item to `lst[1]` causes `lst[2]` to also see that change.

This is a classic mistake people make with pointers and references. Here's the simple analogy. You have a piece of paper. On it, you write the address of someone's house. You now take that piece of paper, and photocopy it twice so you end up with three pieces of paper with the same address written on them. Now, take the *first* piece of paper, scribble out the address written on it, and write a new address to *someone else's* house. Did the address written on the other two pieces of paper change? No. That's *exactly* what your code did, though. That's *why* the other two items don't change. Further, imagine that the owner of the house with address that is *still* on the second piece of paper builds an add-on garage to their house. Now I ask you, does the house whose address is on the *third* piece of paper have an add-on garage? Yes, it does, because it's *exactly* the same house as the one whose address is written on the *second* piece of paper. This explains *everything* about your second code example.

<sup>1</sup>: You didn't expect Python to invoke a "copy constructor" did you? Puke.

Comment: +1 for `id()`. That will be useful.

Comment: Thanks for `id(x)`, and the garage build-on is a nice example for pointer editing.

Answer (score 5):

This is because sequence multiplication merely repeats the references. When you write `[[]] * 2`, you create a new list with two elements, but both of these elements are the *same* object in memory, namely an empty list. Hence, a change in one is reflected in the other. The comprehension, by contrast, creates a *new, independent* list on each iteration:

```
>>> l1 = [[]] * 2
>>> l2 = [[] for _ in xrange(2)]
>>> l1[0] is l1[1]
True
>>> l2[0] is l2[1]
False
```

Comment: I didn't think to try the "is" operator, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

They are referencing the same lists.

There are similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605024/python-using-the-multiply-operator-to-create-copies-of-objects-in-lists) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688223/python-list-multiplication-3-makes-3-lists-which-mirror-each-other-when)

And from the [FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list):

> " * doesn’t create copies, it only creates references to the existing
>   objects."

Comment: +1 for the link to Python docs.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess that using multiplication in the form [[]] * x causes Python to store a reference to a single cell is correct.

So you end up with a list of 3 references to the same list.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what is happening in your first example is that a list is being created with multiple references to the same inner list.  Here's a breakdown.

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = [a]
>>> c = b * 3  # c now contains three references to a
>>> d = [ a for _ in xrange(4) ]  # and d contains four references to a
>>> print c
[[], [], []]
>>> print d
[[], [], [], []]
>>> a.append(3)
>>> print c
[[3], [3], [3]]
>>> print d
[[3], [3], [3], [3]]
>>> x = [[]] * 3  # shorthand equivalent to c
>>> print x
[[], [], []]
>>> x[0].append(3)
>>> print x
[[3], [3], [3]]
```

The above is equivalent to your first example.  Now that each list is given its own variable, hopefully it is clearer why.  `c[0] is c[1]` will evaluate as `True`, because both expressions evaluate to the same object (`a`).

Your second example creates multiple different inner list objects.

```
>>> c = [[], [], []]  # this line creates four different lists
>>> d = [ [] for _ in xrange(3) ]  # so does this line
>>> c[0].append(4)
>>> d[0].append(5)
>>> print c
[[4], [], []]
>>> print d
[[5], [], []]
```