# How to append an element of a sublist in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists in the form:

```
list = [[3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
```

And I want to split it into two lists, one with the x values of each sublist and one with the y values of each sublist.

I currently have this:

```
x = y = []
for sublist in list:
    x.append(sublist[0])
    y.append(sublist[1])
```

But that returns this, and I don't know why:

```
x = [3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3]
y = [3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By doing `x = y = []` you are creating `x` and `y` and referencing them to the same list, hence the erroneous output. (The Object IDs are same below)

```
>>> x = y = []
>>> id(x)
43842656
>>> id(y)
43842656
```

If you fix that, you get the correct result.

```
>>> x = []
>>> y = []
>>> for sublist in lst:
        x.append(sublist[0])
        y.append(sublist[1])


>>> x
[3, 3, 3]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3]
```

Although, this could be made pretty easier by doing.

`x,y = zip(*lst)`

**P.S.** - Please don't use `list` as a variable name, it shadows the builtin.

Comment: The `zip` solution is very neat.

Answer (score 4):

When you say `x = y = []`, you're causing `x` and `y` to be a reference to the *same* list. So when you edit one, you edit the other. There is a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17702997/2452770) about how references work.

Therefore you can use your code if you say instead

```
x = []; y = []
```

You also might want to try `zip`:

```
lst = [[3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
x,y = zip(*lst)
```

And as Sukrit says, don't use `list` as a variable name (or `int` or `str` or what have you) because though it is a Python built-in (load up an interpreter and type `help(list)` - the fact that something pops up means Python has pre-defined `list` to mean something) Python will cheerfully let you redefine (a.k.a. shadow) it. Which can break your code later.

Answer (score 2):

That's because when you construct x and y like `x = y = []` then x and y point to the same list. If you want to make them different lists, you should declare them like

```
x = []
y = []
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `x = y = []` meaning x is pointing to y which is pointing to the list so whenever you append to one, you are appending to the other.  Change the code to something like this:

```
x = [] 
y = []
for sublist in list:
    x.append(sublist[0])
    y.append(sublist[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
x = [i[0] for i in list]
y = [i[1] for i in list]
```