# Difference between [[]]*3 and [[] for i in range(3)]

Tags: python, list

I have been using Python for some years now but just noticed a very confusing thing.

```
a=[[]]*3
a[0].append(3)
```

and

```
a=[[] for i in range(3)]
a[0].append(3)
```

do not have the same effect even though the type (list) is the same.
The first yields `a=[[3], [3], [3]]`, the second `a=[[3],[],[]]` (as expected).

Does anybody have an explanation?

Comment: so many duplicates ...

Comment: @jonrsharpe That is so close to an exact duplicate it just blew my mind!

Comment: And the question is _about_ duplicates. It's a metaduplicate?

Comment: @wim, perhaps but how do you search for them?

Comment: In the spirit of the duplicates, here are 3 ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702937/generating-sublists-using-multiplication-unexpected-behavior  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/unexpected-feature-in-a-python-list-of-lists  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058458/python-list-index

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`[[]]*3` creates a list with three *references* to the same list object:

```
>>> lst = [[]]*3
>>> # The object ids of the lists in 'lst' are the same
>>> id(lst[0])
25130048
>>> id(lst[1])
25130048
>>> id(lst[2])
25130048
>>>
```

`[[] for i in range(3)]` creates a list with three *unique* list objects:

```
>>> lst = [[] for i in range(3)]
>>> # The object ids of the lists in 'lst' are different
>>> id(lst[0])
25131768
>>> id(lst[1])
25130008
>>> id(lst[2])
25116064
>>>
```