# How do you update nested dictionaries in python with overlapping keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I only want to update 1 dictionary value in a dictionary, but it seems to update the union of 2 keys:

```
Y = dict(zip(['A', 'B'], [dict.fromkeys(range(2010,2014), [])] * 2))
zz = {'A':{2012: [(666,999)], 2013: []}, 'B':{2010:[], 2011:[(666,999)]}}

Y['A'][2012] = zz['A'][2012]
```

Result:

```
{'A': {2010: [], 2011: [], 2012: [(666, 999)], 2013: []}, 'B': {2010: [], 2011: [], 2012: [(666, 999)], 2013: []}}
```

I only want to update 2012 of 'A'.

I am a beginner python programmer.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you assigning to `zz` twice?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part:

```
[dict.fromkeys(range(2010,2014), [])] * 2
```

creates a list where both elements are the same dict object. Furthermore, in that single dict, all 4 values are the same list object.

This part:

```
Y['A'][2012] = zz['A'][2012]
```

takes the list object stored in `zz['A'][2012]` and makes `Y['A'][2012]` also refer to that list.

You could make independent dicts with independent lists by doing the following:

```
Y = {key1: {key2: [] for key2 in range(2010, 2014)} for key1 in ['A', 'B']}
```

As I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `Y['A'][2012] = zz['A'][2012]`, I can't offer a solution there.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
[dict.fromkeys(range(2010,2014), [])] * 2
```

creates two same dictionaries, instead of two copies of identical dictionary. So, `Y['A'][2012]` is the same thing as `Y['B'][2012]`.

You can fix it by doing:

```
y = dict(zip(['A', 'B'], [dict.fromkeys(range(2010,2014), []) for _ in [_,_]]))
```

Related:

[List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/unexpected-feature-in-a-python-list-of-lists)

[Generating sublists using multiplication ( * ) unexpected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702937/generating-sublists-using-multiplication-unexpected-behavior)

[Nested List Indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058458/python-list-index)