# assign value in list of list

Tags: python, list, assign

I just want to ask a simple question 
I created a list of list and want to change one value in the list by index it:

```
A = [[0] * 3] * 3
print A, A[0][0]
A[0][0] = 34343
print A

The result is:
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]] 0
[[34343, 0, 0], [34343, 0, 0], [34343, 0, 0]]
```

Why this happens?Where am I wrong?

Comment: Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702937/generating-sublists-using-multiplication-unexpected-behavior

Comment: Solved. I know the problem now