# Editing 2D lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a 2D list in python as follows:

```
b = [[0] * 3] * 3 # 3 * 3
```

Now if I want to make the first element of the first row to be 1, I am doing this:

```
b[0][0] = 1
```

But if I print b, it is making the first element of every row to be 1, something like this:

```
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

What is the problem with my approach? Please suggest some alternatives to create a 2D list in python.

Comment: Some good detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17702937/7954504

Comment: You are creating multiple references to same list. One alternative to create a 2D list will be with copy : `b = [([0]*3).copy() for i in range(0,3)]` .